# Renaming multiple files by adding an integer value of 1

Tags: bash

I have multiple svg files....and I need to rename them by adding 1.

```
0.svg  -->  1.svg
1.svg  -->  2.svg
2.svg  -->  3.svg
```

etc...

What would be the best way to do this using the linux terminal?

Comment: Do they have to stay in the same order, or can you simply rename `0.svg` to the last position?

Comment: Eric, I guess I don't understand your question. What do you mean last position?

Comment: If you have files named `0.svg`, `1.svg`, and `2.svg`, the easiest way to get files named `1.svg`, `2.svg`, and `3.svg` is to rename `0.svg` to `3.svg`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to process the files backwards so you don't overwrite existing files while renaming. Use parameter expansion to extract the numbers from the file names.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=(?.svg)
for (( i = ${#files[@]} - 1; i >= 0; --i )) ; do
    n=${files[i]%.svg}
    mv $n.svg $(( n + 1 )).svg
done
```

If the files can have names of different length (e.g. `9.svg, 10.svg`) the solution will be more complex, as you need to sort the files numerically rather than lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the case that the filename numbers have multiple digits, please try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r num; do
    new="$(( num + 1 )).svg"
    mv -- "$num.svg" "$new"
done < <(
for f in *.svg; do
    n=${f%.svg}
    echo "$n"
done | sort -rn
)
```

Comment: This may work in the OP's situation, but it will go wrong if the directory has no '.svg' files, if SVG file bases are not decimal numbers, or (possibly) if bases have leading zeros.  All files with bases that look like identifiers (e.g. 'image.svg' will silently be renamed to '1.svg' because Bash arithmetic treats unset variables as having value zero (unless `set -o nounset` is in effect).

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code is intended to operate safely and cleanly no matter what is in the  current directory:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s extglob    # Enable extended globbing (+(...), ...)

# Put the file base numbers in a sparse array.
# (Bash automatically keeps such arrays sorted by increasing indices.)
sparse_basenums=()
for svgfile in +([0-9]).svg ; do
    # Skip files with extra leading zeros (e.g. '09.svg')
    [[ $svgfile == 0[0-9]*.svg ]] && continue

    basenum=${svgfile%.svg}
    sparse_basenums[$basenum]=$basenum
done

# Convert the sparse array to a non-sparse array (preserving order)
# so it can be processed in reverse order with a 'for' loop
basenums=( "${sparse_basenums[@]}" )

# Process the files in reverse (i.e. decreasing) order by base number
for ((i=${#basenums[*]}-1; i>=0; i--)) ; do
    basenum=${basenums[i]}
    mv -i -- "$basenum.svg" "$((basenum+1)).svg"
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` prevents bad behaviour if the directory doesn't contain any files whose names are a decimal number followed by '.svg'.  Without it the code would try to process a file called '+([0-9]).svg'.
- `shopt -s extglob` enables a richer set of globbing patterns than the default.  See the 'extglob' section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for details.
- The usefulness of `sparse_basenums` depends on the fact that Bash arrays can have arbitrary non-negative integer indices, that arrays with gaps in their indices are stored efficiently (sparse arrays), and that elements in arrays are always stored in order of increasing index.  See [Arrays (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) for more information.
- The code skips files whose names have extra leading zeros ('09.svg', but not '0.svg') because it can't handle them safely as it is now.  Trying to treat '09' as a  number causes an error because it's treated as an illegal octal number.  That is easily fixable, but there could still be problems if, for instance, you had both '9.svg' and '09.svg' (they would *both* naturally be renamed to '10.svg').
- The code uses `mv -i` to prompt for user input in case something goes wrong and it tries to rename a file to one that already exists.
- Note that the code will silently do the wrong thing (due to arithmetic overflow) if the numbers are too big (e.g. '99999999999999999999.svg').  The problem is fixable.